# Can Selenium IDE verify text on an XML page

Tags: xml, selenium-ide

I have an application that for one of its pages returns an XML string (type text/xml). The result is returned "inline" so that when I load that page in Firefox I see the XML string.

I want to use the Selenium IDE plugin in Firefox to verify that some text is present on this page. However, when I try to do this with the `VerifyTextPresent` command I get the error `Couldn't access document.body. Is this HTML page fully loaded?`.

Is it even possible to do this kind of check in Selenium on XML output? If so, how?

Here is a snippet of what the page produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<alerts time_generated="2011-01-20 20:34:01" version="2.00" time_generated_epoch="1295584441">
  <alert>
    <client_updates/>
    <contact_firstname>Brian</contact_firstname>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium does not natively support verifying text present in an XML page.  However, there is an [assertTextPresentXML](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/assertTextPresentXML) extension available.