# How to use Selenium IDE to verify text present on XML page?

Tags: xml, xpath, selenium, selenium-ide

This [previously asked question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755436/can-selenium-ide-verify-text-on-an-xml-page) answer was to use a plugin but that plugin is no longer maintained or even available. Without using a plugin, how do you verify text present on an XML page?

For example, how do you verify that the URL for a test page is present on the sitemap.xml for your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use assertElementPresent in conjunction with xPath:

```
store  "http://yourwebsite.com"  baseURL
store  your/test/page/  test_page_URL
open  ${baseURL}/sitemap.xml
assertElementPresent  //*[contains(text(),'${baseURL}/${test_page_URL}')]
```

Selenium IDE is not designed for XML pages so it took much experimentation before I was able to figure how to get xPath to work to find the text.

That last line basically says:

Assert existence of the string '${baseURL}/${test_page_URL}' anywhere on the page (with the values for variables baseURL and test_page_URL plugged in).